# How to remove hydrofluorosilicic acid from water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water, purification, water-treatment

I'd like to come as close as possible to pure water. Would a KF filter remove [hydrofluorosilicic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluorosilicic_acid)? If not, what would?

I could not find the concentration of hydrofluorosilicic acid, but would like to get this as close to zero as possible. The average reported chloride level is 12.4 mg/L. Otherwise, I don't know of any other additives. However, since this is municipal and treated water, it likely has whatever gets flushed yet not removed.

Comment: The best way to produce pure water out of any aqueous solution is distillation. It is also possible to use anionic and cationic resins : this will remove all dissolved ions. It will not remove bacterias.

Comment: @Maurice. Thanks for your reply. Is it possible for a regular person to buy one of these cationic or anionic resins? Considering the chloramines (I just learned from amonia), I'm not worried about bacterias.

Comment: Yes. These resins are on sale. You have to choose anionic resins, and not the more familiar cationic resins. You can find a lot of different offers on Google by typing "Anionic resins". I know the resins made by Dow Co. They are called Dowex. I can mention Dowex 1X4 (also called Amberchrom 1X4), which costs 130€ for 100 g. or Dowex 21K chloride, which costs 80 € for 100 g. Or Dowex Marathon MSA chloride, which costs 52 € for 100 g. There are usually several degree of mesh. 100 mesh correspond to beads 0.15 mm diameter. 200 mesh is 0.075 mm diameter. 50 mesh is 0.3 mm diameter

Comment: I think that almost answers the question. Can I assume KF from Berkey does *not* remove the HF acid? @Maurice, please reply as an answer so I can give you credit for your help.

Comment: I don't know what is "KF from Berkey". Never heard of this ...